# Git equivalent for "hg log" with a template?

Tags: git, mercurial, versioning

I've found a way to generate a semver-compliant version string from an appropriately-tagged Mercurial repository using `hg log` with a template. It looks like this:

```
hg log -r . --template "{latesttag('re:^[vV]\d+\.\d+\.\d+') % '{node}|{tag}.{distance}|{tag}{ifeq(distance, '1', '', '-build{distance}')}{ifeq(branch, 'default', '', '+{branch}')}'}"
```

This returns three things, the revision ID of the commit matching the tag pattern, the .NET `System.Version`-compliant version string, and a semver 2.0-compliant version string using the tag distance as prerelease information if greater than 1 (i.e. more actual commits after the tag revision), and using the branch name as build metadata if it is any value other than "default" (e.g. "hotfix-JIRA-123").

I don't mind not being able to get this all formatted in one `hg log` command, as long as I can get all the values to format it afterwards. This is just gravy on Mercurial's part.

However the only way I can see to do the same in git would be to use multiple commands, like so:

```
REM Returns the tag, tag distance, and node ID "abbreviated" to 40 chars (i.e. not abbreviated, LOLZ)
git describe --tags --long --match "v*.*.*" --abbrev=40
REM Returns the branch name
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

If `git describe` could additionally return the branch name in any way, that would solve my problem, but I can't actually see any one command in git that will return all these values, having already filtered to a tagged revision like these commands do.

I can carry on as I am, I'm just wondering if there's something I'm missing.

Comment: You're not missing anything here. The closest Git comes to the flexibility of Mercurial log templates is Git's `%` formatting directives in `git log`, but there is no formatting directive that does what `git describe` does, and `git describe` doesn't do formatting directives.

Comment: Maybe asking a separate question about methods to generate semver #s from git would be useful... a quick Google does seem to turn up some approaches. But I'm not a git guy...